# Change page type in run time (Normal x Modal Page)

Tags: oracle, modal-dialog, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

As far as I know this is not possible.

But...

Does anyone know how to modify the page type while running the application?

Problem:

I need a normal page to work in certain cases as a modal page. I know I can copy and create modal with the same components, but this makes it difficult to maintain ...

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not feasible, but you could create two Apex applications; and one of them would contain a [Global Page](https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/HTMDB/creating-a-global-page-to-display-components-on-every-page.htm#HTMDB06002) with all your forms, controls, etc.  Then you would create two pages in that application, one modal, one normal. All the components on the Global Page render on every page in that application. Then your other application would link to the appropriate page.

You would need to manage session sharing, etc. but it could be possible.

Comment: Thank you Mark, but in my case all the pages consists in reports. But, these reports are related and the user can navigate between these reports to find some information. Each report can have a column(s) with a link to other(s) report, but I would like these links opens in a modal page. But, the standard page of these reports still necessary, the user can start navigate between any report. In some cases, we think is best to the user see this info in a modal, instead to go to the standard page. And are there a lot of reports (100 or more). Thank for the suggest.